# How to Cast Optional<Double> to Optional<int> in Swift

Tags: swift

Is there a built in way to convert an optional double to an optional Int in Swift?

I expect that the function should cast `Some` Double to `Some` Int and `nil -> nil`.

Does this exist? I know that I could create a simple extension but I'm hoping that there's something built-in. When I use `Int()` I get the expected error of `Value of optional type 'Double?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Double'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no built-in other than the Int initializer and you do need to unwrap it before trying to initialize it unless you create an extension and do an optional binding syntax. So the only thing you can do is something like:

```
extension BinaryFloatingPoint {
    func integer<B: BinaryInteger>() -> B { .init(self) }
    var int: Int { integer() }
}
```

---

```
let double: Double? = 2.5
let int = double?.int   // optional integer 2
```

Comment: Without an extension: `let int = double.map(Int.init)`

Comment: @MartinR yes that's an option. I still prefer the extension way

Comment: Both approaches are good. Voted. Given that it’s a short expression, I tend to prefer using `map()`, but that’s personal preference.